# after installing Python3 and Django in Windows 7, problems with web page display

Tags: python, django

I have some trouble after installing django in Windows. 
The admin page, "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/" displays in text mode. 
I suspect this is a problem with the environment variables, but I can't find any details on how they're supposed to be set up.
Any help?

Here are some details:
    python --version
    #Python 3.7.4
    python -m django --version
    #2.2.5
I created and started the environment and project: 
    python -m venv ll_env
    ll_env\Scripts\activate
    pip install django
    django-admin startproject learning_log .
    python manage.py migrate
    python manage.py runserver

Path: 
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\

Env Variables: plenty, but none referencing Python or Django

I tried other install instructions from djangoproject, with the same result

django-admin check

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mihai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py",
line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "**main**", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Mihai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py",
line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\WorkPython\learning_log\ll_env\Scripts\django-admin.exe__main__.py",
 line 9, in 
  File "c:\workpython\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\manageme
nt__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\workpython\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\manageme
nt__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\workpython\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\manageme
nt\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "c:\workpython\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\manageme
nt\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\workpython\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\manageme
nt\commands\check.py", line 64, in handle
    fail_level=getattr(checks, options['fail_level']),
  File "c:\workpython\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\manageme
nt\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "c:\workpython\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\manageme
nt\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "c:\workpython\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\r
egistry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "c:\workpython\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\c
aches.py", line 14, in check_default_cache_is_configured
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "c:\workpython\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__
.py", line 79, in **getattr**
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\workpython\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__
.py", line 64, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but setti
ngs are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_S
ETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: This is most probably caused by a wrong HTTP `content-type` header sent by the server. Presumably it is set to `text/plain` instead of `text/html; charset=utf-8`. If you use Firefox, you can check the HTTP response headers by pressing `F12`, clicking on `Network` and selecting a request.

Comment: Thank you the reply. It looks like I manged to break Python trying to fix this problem, now I can't even migrate the DB: python manage.py migrate :   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'.

Comment: I checked again, the header is fine.  
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 09 Sep 2019 23:02:03 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.4
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8